# What is a good plotting library for .Net?

Tags: .net, windows, graphing

I'm writing some data acquisition software and need a gui plotting library that is fast enough to do realtime updated graphs.  I've been using Nplot which is pretty good for a free library, but I'm wondering if there are any better libraries (preferably free or cheap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good post about this [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gbarnett/archive/2008/06/03/visualising-data.aspx) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gbarnett/archive/2008/03/23/free-graphing-libraries-for-net-my-thoughts.aspx). I have also used NPlot in our last project since it's easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you need something to display in a WinForms app then you can try out the free [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). If it is ASP.NET then I recently have used [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) with some great results.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not free. But we have had very good results with Nevron. Their support is excellent as well.

Another good option is TeeCharts.

Answer (score 2):

ZedGraph is not WinForms only, there's a web control too. It's very good.

Answer (score 2):

Definetly go for Zedgraph, we have been using this for years and it is very good in 'real-time' graphing. Zedgraph is very well documented and there are many examples available.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is your main concern, nothing better than TeeChart. The fastLine series it provides plots 10 million points in a second. And recently they have introduced it for realtime as well. I was blown away by the speed of plotting.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/). It's an open source graphing tool built in flash and can be dynamically updated.

Check out the [Ajax example](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/gallery-js-2.php) for an idea of what it can do.